# I am trying to upload file through node js using multer but I am not getting proper file

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, multer

I am using Multer for file uploading in Node js, but I am not getting proper file. I am trying to upload the image.
I have to upload the imported file on the S3 bucket but the file is not found, I don't know where I am wrong.

Here is my node js code:

```
 import "@tsed/multipartfiles";
    import Path = require("path");
    const rootDir = Path.resolve(__dirname);

    const aws = require("aws-sdk");
    import { Express } from "express";
    import { Controller, Post } from "@tsed/common";
    type MulterFile = Express.Multer.File;
    import { MultipartFile } from "@tsed/multipartfiles";

    @controller("/session")

export class TeleconsultSessionController implements interfaces.Controller {

 @httpPost("/uploadDocuments")
    public async uploadDocument( @MultipartFile() file: MulterFile, req: Request, res: Response) {
        try {                
            aws.config.update({ accessKeyId: "AKIAIYKXXXXXXXXX", secretAccessKey: "iMzE0wfryXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" });
            aws.config.update({ region: "us-east-1" });

            const s3 = new aws.S3();
            s3.upload({
                "Bucket": "teleconsult-development",
                "Key": "image",
                "Body": file
            }, function (err: any, data: any) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }
        catch (err) {
            if (err instanceof ValidationException) {
                res.status(400);
                res.send({ error: err.getMessage() });

            } else {
                res.status(500);
                res.send({ error: err.getMessage() });
            }
        }

    }
```

In response when I hit through postman I am getting the value of file as:

Object {------WebKitFormBoundaryAo1BhVpGaB8uYmsw\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name: ""image1"; filename="1528114981689_566_28-1-2

Comment: I would suggest using Presigned URL https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html
You create presigned url on back end and the user upload the file directly to AWS

Answer (score 0):

Uploading files with `multer` will keep files inside server's upload folder first depends on your multer settings.

If a file is successfully uploaded by multer, you will get the following data from `req.file`.

```
{ 
fieldname: 'file',
originalname: 'sample.jpg',
encoding: '7bit',
mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
destination: './uploads/',
filename: 'd1fccf5dc0125937f6fbe7a4dacfc069',
path: 'uploads/d1fccf5dc0125937f6fbe7a4dacfc069',
size: 23904 
}
```

The `path` value I will be using in the example below is not a directory. Multer will change your filename withiout an extension.

You will need to read that uploaded file as fileStream and then upload it to S3 will works.

For example:

```
let path = req.file;
let fileStream = fs.createReadStream(file.path);
fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
    if (err) { throw err; }
});
fileStream.on('open', function () {
    s3.upload({
        "Bucket": "yourBucketName",
        "Key": file.originalname,
        "Body": fileStream
    }, function (err: any, data: any) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: I did this but I am getting the path of API not the exact location

Comment: this is my API:    localhost:3000/session/uploadDocuments and it is giving me path as   D:/session/uploadDocuments

Comment: But I am not getting req.file it is undefined

Comment: No dude still it is giving me same error file as undefined

Comment: Your file need to upload as `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: Yes I am doing that only but still it is giving me undefined

Comment: I am send my content-Type=multipart/form-data through postman